# How get JSON field in views for serialization

Tags: python, json, django-rest-framework

Hi I'm new in DRF and need a help . I write API.Then user ,for example, put in url http://api.example/people , then he get value from "attributes" -"name": "John","age": 80,"gender": "male". I get this data from db and give information for user, that`s why I must serialize this data.

```
        {
        "name": "John",
        "age": 80,
        "gender": "male"
      }
```

field "type"  is dynamic for example can be "animal" http://api.example/animal .Field "included" is JSONField() in model .My problem is in point, when I must get field fields from "included" in views.py for serialization , because it is json and I don't know how I must work with it . Maybe json.dump() but then I got str and can't convert in dict . Maybe someone give me some advice, please.

```
{
  "data": [{
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "title": "JSON:API paints my bikeshed!",
      "body": "The shortest article. Ever.",
      "created": "2015-05-22T14:56:29.000Z",
      "updated": "2015-05-22T14:56:28.000Z"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "author": {
        "data": {"id": "42", "type": "people"}
      }
    }
  }],
  "included": [
    {
      "type": "people",
      "id": "42",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "John",
        "age": 80,
        "gender": "male"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I

Comment: Could you explain what you want to achieve? Do you want to get data (e.g. "id") out of your `json`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it's overall unclear what the ask is. There is also no code provided, so it's hard to make a guess at what approach is currently being used.

Comment: CodeIsLaw, I need to get data "name", "age" and "male" out of your json when user put in url type "people" for example

Answer (score 0):

Getting specific data out of `json` can be done as follows. If your json_data looks like this e.g.:

```
json_data = [{"id": "1"}]
```

Than you could get the `id` like this:

```
id : int = json_data['id']
```

So basically you just need your `json` data and can access all values by its "name" using brackets (`[]`)

Answer (score 0):

you probably want json.loads
and to load it into ordereddict, not normal dict, you need to provide additional argument

example:

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict
data = json.loads(some_json_data, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDcit)
```